# Captions for tables in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, captions

I am attempting to add a caption to a table in a Beamer presentation. The caption I would like to add is "this is my caption" but when I compile the caption reads "Table : this is my caption". What instruction can I use that will remove "Table : " from my caption? A simple example is provided below. Thanks...

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\hline
Column A  & Column B & Column C \\ \hline
Blah      & 100      & 110      \\
Blah blah & 200      & 220      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is my caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can load the `booktabs` package and then use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` to get nicer-looking horizontal lines in your tables.

Comment: I'll give that a go @Svend. Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this with the command

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
```

Put this line in the preamble if you want this behavior for all your captions, or inside the specific float if you want it to be local.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\hline
Column A  & Column B & Column C \\ \hline
Blah      & 100      & 110      \\
Blah blah & 200      & 220      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is my caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]